# How to project only the fields present in an array in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation

there is a document schema that has an array field called `"updatedFields"` which contains some fields names that you will find in `"oldDocument"` and
`"newDocument"` objects. Here is its picture.

[image]

Now I want to project only those fields which exist in `"updatedFields"` array from `"newDocument"` and `"oldDocument"` like below:

```
 $project : { 
    "oldDocument.Modified":1,
    "oldDocument.Status":1,
    "newDocument.Modified":1,
    "newDocument.Status":1
 }
```

Does anyone know how to build the project clause base on the fields' names in the array? I need a MongoDB query, not js code.

Comment: Please provide some sample data set in json documents and the corresponding expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$objectToArray` in order to format the keys as values, `$filter` them according to the `updatedFields` array and then use `$arrayToObject` to make them keys again.

Edit: using `$map` inside the filter to cast dates to strings, according to a request on the comments.

Something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      oldDocumentArr: {$objectToArray: "$oldDocument"},
      newDocumentArr: {$objectToArray: "$newDocument"},
      updatedFields: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      oldDocumentFilter: {
        $map: {
          input: {
            $filter: {
              input: "$oldDocumentArr",
              as: "item",
              cond: {$in: ["$$item.k", "$updatedFields"]
              }
            }
          },
          "as": "obj",
          "in": {
            "k": "$$obj.k",
            "v": {$toString: "$$obj.v"}
          }
        }
      },
      newDocumentFilter: {
        $map: {
          input: {
            $filter: {
              input: "$newDocumentArr",
              as: "item",
              cond: {$in: ["$$item.k", "$updatedFields"]
              }
            }
          },
          "as": "obj",
          "in": {
            "k": "$$obj.k",
            "v": {$toString: "$$obj.v"}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      oldDocument: {$arrayToObject: "$oldDocumentFilter"},
      newDocument: {$arrayToObject: "$newDocumentFilter"},
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

As you can see on the [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Bj6WkJFFPkA)

Comment: Thanks, Would you let me know how to convert the data value to string while filtering the arrays? Only date type

Comment: If you want to convert ISODate to string, just use `$toString`. For example `d: {$toString: '$d'}`

Comment: Let me know if it is working for you

Comment: Please edit the answer and include the date conversion

Comment: How can I convert the date to string in the filter clause?

Comment: I updated the playground link: https://mongoplayground.net/p/zJRpCZiKGVe. Why do you want to change it inside the filter? It can work even without changing, but if you want to change, I whould do it before

Comment: If you want the date as string, you can do it like this: https://mongoplayground.net/p/_rJP9HISCTL

Comment: I have to convert the date's value to string for a complex reason. The reason why I want to do the conversion in the filter clause is that updatedFields is a dynamic array and may contain a field that is missing in the project that is responsible for conversion. So it is better to convert them in the filter clause. I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: You can map inside the filter: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Bj6WkJFFPkA

Comment: updated the answer with your request